# ERROR:0@0.504 global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 cv::obsensor::getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range in intruder catcher program

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

The following program gives a warning and takes photo from the webcam every time someone presses any keys on the keyboard or click mouse keys.

```
import time
import pyttsx3
import cv2
import os
from pynput import keyboard, mouse

# Initialize the text-to-speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()

# Function to create a folder for photos if it doesn't exist


def create_photo_folder():
    folder_name = "warning_photos"
    if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
        os.makedirs(folder_name)
    return folder_name


# Initialize the webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if the webcam is opened successfully
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Unable to access the webcam.")
    exit()

# Get the folder name for photos
photo_folder = create_photo_folder()

# Function to capture and save a photo


def capture_photo():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        photo_filename = os.path.join(photo_folder, f"warning_{timestamp}.jpg")
        cv2.imwrite(photo_filename, frame)


# Function to announce the warning


def announce_warning():
    message = "Stay away from this PC. You are not authorized to use this."
    engine.say(message)
    engine.runAndWait()
    capture_photo()  # Capture and save a photo


# Initialize a counter for warnings
warning_count = 0

# Set up flags to indicate if the program should keep running
keyboard_activity = False
mouse_activity = False

# Function to handle key press event


def on_key_press(key):
    global keyboard_activity
    keyboard_activity = True


# Function to handle mouse click event


def on_mouse_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global mouse_activity
    mouse_activity = True


# Create keyboard and mouse listeners
keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_key_press)
mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_mouse_click)

# Start the listeners
keyboard_listener.start()
mouse_listener.start()

# Start the countdown
countdown = 10 * 60  # 10 minutes in seconds

while countdown > 0:
    # Check if there's been any keyboard or mouse activity
    if keyboard_activity or mouse_activity:
        announce_warning()
        keyboard_activity = False
        mouse_activity = False
        warning_count += 1  # Increment the warning count

    time.sleep(1)
    countdown -= 1

# Clean up
keyboard_listener.stop()
mouse_listener.stop()
engine.stop()
cap.release()  # Release the webcam

# Print the warning count
print(f"Total warnings issued: {warning_count}")

# End of the program
```

It was working fine before but now I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR:0@0.504] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 cv::obsensor::getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
Error: Unable to access the webcam.
```

I even tried to disable and enable the camera but it is still not working. Can someone please guide me how to solve this error?

Comment: have you tried turning it off and on again?